# Slot Options in Common Lisp structure without specifying any slot value

Tags: struct, common-lisp, slots

Is there any way to specify a *slot-option* for a struct slot without having to give it a default value? This can be of benefit e.g. when defining a base structure from which other structures would inherit, specifying the `:type`s or `:read-only` without giving an initial value would look nicer i think.

The following structure definition leads to an error since the initial value is missing:

```
(defstruct s
  (x :type number :read-only t)
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

No. One (of many) difference between [`defstruct`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defstr.htm) and [`defclass`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defcla.htm) is that all structure slots always have a value, and not specifying the default is equivalent to specifying `nil` default.

Note that

> The restriction against issuing a warning for type mismatches between a *slot-initform* and the corresponding slot's `:type` option is necessary because a *slot-initform* must be specified in order to specify slot options; in some cases, no suitable default may exist.

In your case, I recommend:

```lisp
(defstruct s
  (x (error "x is required") :type number :read-only t))
```

in which case `(make-s)` will signal an error, while `(make-s :x 10)` will work.